# DJANGO - Admin Action

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-authentication

I'd like to create a website with for car dealer with admin and allow dealers to add, edit, delete car.

My problem is that on Django Admin, when I login with any account I see all the cars and I'd like to show only cars attched to connected dealer.

I create a model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import datetime
from brand.models import Brands
from django.urls import reverse

class Car(models.Model):
 dealer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
 brand = models.ForeignKey(Brands, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
 carname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 def __str__(self):
 return '%s %s' % (self.brand, self.carname)
```

Also, when I create a car the dealer's list show all dealers in database, but me I'd like to display only connected account name.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django Admin class you can define `has_view_permission` method https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_view_permission

for example:

```py
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_view_permission(request, obj=None):
        if request.user == obj.dealer:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```